# How to change page numbering and section numbering?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, page-numbering

I am pretty new to LaTeX. Right now I have this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom= 3.2cm]{geometry}
%
%
%
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   %{graphicx} in order to load pictures.
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}  %{babel} enables to choose a language.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %[utf8]{inputenc} enables UTF8-characters not only ASCII.
\usepackage{ae}     %Uses "Latin Modern" instead of "Computer Modern".
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}%Automatically turns all internal references into "hyperlinks". "pdfborder={0 0 0}" disables red border around hyperrefs.


\begin{document}

\input{./Title.tex}
\input{./blabla.tex}

\tableofcontents




\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{./Abstract.tex}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\input{./Introduction.tex}
\input{./MyStuff.tex}


\end{document}
```

What I am trying to achieve with

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

is a page numbering scheme like this:

> I. Abstract.....I
>
> 1. Introduction..1
> 2. MyStuff.......2

Plus I want the section I included into chapters to be numbered in **arabic** too.

The current output is different though. All chapters, sections and pages are still numbered in arabic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a short sample of what's in `abstract.tex`? If you don't have other numbered parts in the front matter (that is, before the first "regular" chapter) it's probably better *not* to give a number to the abstract.

Comment: Abstract.tex contains two sections a german and a english version.

Comment: Still I don't think it's a good idea to number them: the name is sufficient.

Comment: Should I put it before the tableofcontents or somehow remove the numbering?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the scheme I propose; the `kantlipsum` package is just to produce mock text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom= 3.2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for mock text


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\input{./Title.tex}
%\input{./blabla.tex}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{headings}

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
%\input{./Abstract.tex}
\chapter{\abstractname}
\kant[1]

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\chapter{\abstractname}
\kant[2]
\end{otherlanguage}

\endgroup

\mainmatter

%\input{./Introduction.tex}
%\input{./MyStuff.tex}

\chapter{Introduktion}
\kant[3]

\section{Title}
\kant



\end{document}
```

I use the fact that chapters in the front matter are not numbered and use a trick for getting two chapters in the same page, which assumes that your two abstracts fit.

However my opinion is that *all* pages should have a number, even if it doesn't appear. So the abstracts will be on page, say **vii** (title page, back of title page, dedication, back of dedication, table of contents in two pages).